# FirstViewController doesn't work on removing the subview of SecondViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, ibaction

First View Controller

I'm using a UIStoryBoard to allow the FirstViewController to add the view of second ViewController as a subview. On removing the sub view the

```
  - (IBAction) btnMoveTo:(id)sender
{

 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
 UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Second"];
 vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
 [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:NO];

}
```

SecondViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
   self.view.opaque = YES;
   self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}

 - (IBAction) withDraw:(id)sender{
     [self.view removeWithZoomOutAnimation:2 option:nil];
    }
```

When I access the withDraw Function, the view of the SecondViewController is removed and firstViewController is back. However when I use the button to access the - (IBAction) btnMoveTo:(id)sender function. It doesn't work. Nothing really happens. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For all I know, your problem could be from the StoryBoard file (90%), Check the names there, and make sure `secondViewController` actually has something inside it (you can't even tell if it works when the view is empty with clearColor as a BG). Also make sure you linked your IBOutlets properly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try declare the *vc like this:
UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Second"];

Comment: I just crete a demo, and it works well. Maybe you forget set the secondViewController Identifier in attribute inspector.

Answer (score 0):

It worked

```
- (IBAction) withDraw:(id)sender{
 [self.view removeWithZoomOViewControllerutAnimation:2 option:nil];

  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
  UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"First"];
  vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
  [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:NO];
}
```

I added another instance of the firstViewController by pointing to its identifier. So it brings back FirstViewController to the top.